# How to Suppress "Too Many Spell Errors" in Word Automation?

Tags: visual-c++, error-handling, ms-word, automation, spelling

I am using Visual C++ to Automate Word and make it invisible. However, when adding some texts to a Word document, I will see a “Too many spelling errors” message box. I try to set DisplayAlerts to FALSE, as follows:

```
app.put_DisplayAlerts(FALSE);
```

But that does not work. The “Spelling error” message will still pop up. How to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Best would be to set the language of what you're writing to the document. If the content is not in a particular language (such as programming code) set it to "no proofing".

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/08fb69f0-5e3e-4dd4-a218-f20642556118/how-to-suppress-quottoo-many-spell-errorsquot-in-word-automation?forum=worddev
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @macropod, Thank you very much. I have modified my post on ms forum based on the advice in the article.